# SQLite multiple rows to a single string

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I am accessing an SQLite database using Ruby `sqlite3` gem.

I have a table such as:

```
id | ip      | nick
1  | 1.2.3.4 | abc
2  | 1.2.3.4 | def
3  | 1.2.3.4 | ghi
4  | 1.2.3.4 | jkl
5  | 1.2.3.4 | mno
```

and a query such as:

```
SELECT nick FROM table WHERE ip = '1.2.3.4'
```

but I want a single row returned, with all nicks for that IP address in alphabetical order:

```
nicks = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mto"]
```

What is the best method to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming table name `test`, you can do either:

```
nicks = db.execute( "select nick from test" ).flatten
```

or

```
nicks = db.execute( "select nick from test" ).each_with_object([]) do |row, obj|
    obj << row[0]
end
```